# StringBuilder Formatter

Tags: java

`StringBuilder.append` for large SQL statements looks ugly and formatting to append takes so much time is there any easy way to format the `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` in Java

Comment: If some of the pieces are user input, building SQL statements bit by bit might lead to security issues: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Generally, performing ugly SQL takes so much longer than building the String.

Answer (score 4):

`String.format` may help to make the code more readable:

```
String sql = String.format("select * from %s where %s = ?;", table, field);
```

The `StringBuilder` alternative:

```
String sql = new StringBuilder("select * from ")
                  .append(table)
                  .append(" where ")
                  .append(field)
                  .append(" = ")
                  .append("?")
                  .toString();
```

Comment: prone to sql injection attack

Comment: This was a simple stupid example to show a replacement for something that you would build with string builder. NOTHING ELSE. I know that this (before my edit) was nothing you'd put in production.

Comment: Given that there is no loop a all here I would simply use String concatenation rather than a StringBuilder.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, in a single statement the compiler optimizes it to StringBuilder anyway

Comment: The question was not about application performance but about clean code ("ugly"). String.format is slow but much easier to read.